# ExtJS4 toolbar position of new button

Tags: extjs

I'm adding a button to the htmleditor toolbar. E.g.:

```
this.cmp.getToolbar().add([
    {
        iconCls: 'custom-btn-clear',
        handler: this.remove_all_tags,
        scope: this,
        overflowText: 'Remove formatting'
    }
]);
```

I need to put it on the first position (first from left side). How can I specify buttons position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [insert](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-insert) method.

`myToolbar.insert(0, {});`